# Are side tabs available in Chrome on Linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I've been searching around for this for a while now, and various sites claim different things, so I'm hoping to get a clear answer here:

Is the side tabs/vertical tabs feature available in the Linux version of Chrome, and if so, how do I enable it?

I've tried the `--enable-side-tabs` command line switch with no luck. Also there is no option for this in `about:flags`, as many sites seem to suggest.

I am currently running Chrome version `15.0.861.0 dev` on Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: As far as FRQ's go, [they aren't](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=30531843230a1eb9&hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently side-tabs is a [deprecated feature](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=83008).

Too bad, I too was looking for a way to enable them on Linux and came across that ticket...

Answer (score 0):

The CLI flag is --enable-vertical-tabs (not side tabs), try that, works on a Mac. When started with this parameter, you can right click the tab bar and choose "use vertical tabs".

At least on a Mac, vertical tabs look very ugly though as of yet.